# The best way to running several functions

Tags: function, powershell

i need help with running different functions at the same with the same arguments.

I have a powershell script are build like this:

```
$ObjectsArray = @(Object1, Object2, Object3)

function function1($arg) {
    do something...
}

function function2($arg) {
    do something...
}

function function3($arg) {
    do something...
}



foreach($Objec in ObjectArray) {
    function1 -arg $Object.Name
    function2 -arg $Object.Name
    function3 -arg $Object.Name
}
```

in my script i have many functions and i want optimize the code.

there is any way to run all of these function in one time? maybe with regex?

in all the function i'm use with the same arguments.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please clarify - by directly updating your question - whether (a) you want to avoid having to enumerate the function calls individually (`function1 -arg ...`, then `function2 -arg ...`, ...) or (b) you want the functions to run _in parallel_.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to **avoid the repetition of explicitly enumerating individual function calls** that take the same arguments:

```
# Get function-info objects for the target functions by name pattern
# (wildcard expression), as an array.
# Note: Alternatively, you can store the names explicitly in an array:
#   $funcsToCall = 'function1', 'function2', 'function3'
$funcsToCall = Get-Item function:function?

foreach ($object in $ObjectsArray) {
  # Loop over all functions in the array and call each.
  foreach ($func in $funcsToCall) {
    # Use & (call operator) to call a function
    # by function-info object or name.
    & $func -arg $object.Name
  }
}
```

This will still execute the functions *sequentially*, however.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @OhadAmar (the other poster here won't be notified of your comment - only I was, because it is my answer). Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes, it's possible.

longer answer: you will need to separate the various executions into powershell jobs.  This is sort of multi-threading, but I don't know enough to tell you that it's actually peeling threads from the (virtual) core(s).

Here is how you call an individual job:

```
PS C:\temp\StackWork\csvimport> start-job -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem c:\ | select Mode,Name | ft -w -auto}

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
9      Job9            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Get-ChildItem c:\ | se...
```

There you see the output is not the results of the command, but the properties of the job itself.  That 'State' field is how you check if the job is still running or completed.

Then this is how you get the resulting output of the job:

```
PS C:\temp\StackWork\csvimport> receive-job 9

Mode   Name
----   ----
d----- inetpub
d----- PerfLogs
d-r--- Program Files
d-r--- Program Files (x86)
d----- Python27
d----- Quarantine
d----- Tech
d----- Temp
d-r--- Users
d----- Windows
```

Here is how you get the info on a running job:

```
PS C:\temp\StackWork\csvimport> get-job -Id 9

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
9      Job9            BackgroundJob   Completed     False           localhost
```

Expanding this really depends on what you need to see in the output, and what you need to trigger as a next action.  In your example, it's only really 3 parallel runs, but as you increase you may need to track running jobs and set limits to complete some before starting new ones.  A good rule of thumb I've always heard was two running threads x (# cores -1).

All of that is very specific to your needs, but hopefully this helps with the basis of implementation.